# Difference of 2 sets retained in arrays - C++

Tags: c++, arrays, set, difference

Consider two sets retained in two arrays. Find the union, intersection and difference (relative complement) of the two sets.

I managed to solve the union and the intersection, but the difference is giving me a hard time. Any hints? And if possible, keep it as simple as possible, without functions or more complex aspects, because I'm a beginner and I still have a lot to learn.

Thank you in advance!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
int v1[100], v2[100], u[200], intersection[100], d[100];
unsigned int v1_length, v2_length, i, j, OK = 0, union_length;

cout << "Enter the number of elements of the first array:" << " ";
cin >> v1_length;

cout << "Enter the elements of the first array:" << '\n';

for (i = 0; i < v1_length; i++)
    cin >> v1[i];

cout << "Enter the number of elements of the second array:" << " ";
cin >> v2_length;

cout << "Enter the elements of the second array:" << '\n';

for (i = 0; i < v2_length; i++)
    cin >> v2[i];


//Union

union_length = v1_length;

for (i = 0; i < v1_length; i++)
    u[i] = v1[i];

for (i = 0; i < v2_length; i++)
{
    int ok = 0;
    for (j = 0; !ok && j < v1_length; j++)
        if (v1[j] == v2[i])
            ok = 1;

    if (!ok)
    {
        u[union_length] = v2[i];
        union_length++;
    }
}

cout << "The union of the two sets contained in the arrays is: ";

for (i = 0; i < union_length; i++)
    cout << u[i] << " ";

cout << '\n';


//Intersection

unsigned int k = 0;

cout << "The intersection of the two sets contained in the arrays is: ";

for (i = 0; i < v1_length; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < v2_length; j++)
        if (v1[i] == v2[j])
        {
            intersection[k] = v1[i];
            k++;
        }

for (i = 0; i < k; i++)
    cout << intersection[i] << " ";

cout << '\n';


//Difference

unsigned int l = 0, OK2 = 0;

cout << "The difference of the two sets contained in the arrays is: ";

for (i = 0; i < v1_length; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < v2_length; j++)
    {
        if (v1[i] == v2[j])
            OK2 = 1;
        if (!OK2)
        {
            d[l] = v1[i];
            l++;
        }
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < l; i++)
    cout << d[i] << " ";

cout << '\n';

return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Think how you would word the problem in plain English: add every element from V1 **that is not contained in V2** to the result. Write a function `contains(v, x)` that checks if element `x` is contained in the set `v`. Then apply the above using that function. You can also use that function for the other problems, and greatly simplify your code.

Comment: Union: *add every element from V1 and V2 to the result if the result doesn't already **contain** it*. Intersection: *add every element from V1 that is also **contained** in V2 to the result*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the intersection is the best place to start.  You want the items that only in appear in one of the two arrays, right?

So, for the inner loop, you need to compare all the elements.  Then, if no match was found, you have the a unique element.

You need to add the curly braces {} to the for loop.  I know that curly braces are distracting at times, but over time, you will probably find it safer to almost always include them to avoid confusion.

```
for (i = 0; i < v1_length; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < v2_length; j++) {
        if (v1[i] == v2[j]){
            break; // this item is not unique
        } else if(j == v2_length - 1){
            d[l] = v1[i];  // This is the unique one, add it to the answer array
            l++;
        }

    }

for (i = 0; i < l; i++)
    cout << intersection[l] << " ";

cout << '\n';
```

Comment: @Alina, Thank you for accepting the answer.  Please note that the "else if" condition will only be true on the final iteration of the inner loop.  If the code is able to iterate through the entire inner loop without finding a match, then the given item only exists in one of the two sets.   Also, note that 'l' should never be chosen as a variable name in c++.  I used your variable, but l just does not print very well.  'k', 'm', or 'n' are better.  I often use a longer name like 'answerIndex'.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track!

You're doing a few things wrong. Here are some fixes you can try:

1. Only set `OK2` to `0` once per inner-loop
2. Reset `OK2` to `0` at the end of the inner-loop
3. Only do the insertion into `d` after the inner-loop has completed

As an optimization, consider `break`ing after you set `OK2` to `1`, as you know at that point it can never be set to `0` for the current value pointed to by the outer-loop.